# Converting an OpenCV matrix to C++ matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an OpenCV matrix with size 640*480 and now I would like to convert it to a normal matrix which can be used in c++. What do you suggest me as the best method?

```
//Defining Matrix "a"
cv::Mat a =cv::Mat::zeros(640, 480, CV_32SC1); 
//Filling matrix "a" with integer data
```

According to the above code, how can I have equivalent of matrix "a"  in c++?

Comment: What is a normal matrix in C++?

Comment: Don't? Anything you want done, opencv can do for you. And if it can't, you can just manually loop over the `cv::Mat`.

Comment: my mean is a 2D matrix with integer data. I want to convert an OpenCV matrix (CV::Mat) to a usual matrix

Comment: Can you help me how? because I should do some operation on this matrix, that's y I am trying to convert it first and then apply operations. tnx

Comment: A Mat1i is an integer matrix. I can't think of a reason to get a (don't know really what it means) "normal" matrix, since opencv offers a wide support for  matrices.

Comment: Unless you're trying to convert a Mat into a 2D vector, I don't see the significance of using a "C++ matrix"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the matrix.

```
int mat[640][480];
for (int row = 0; row < a.rows; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < a.cols; col++)
        mat[col][row] = a.at<int>(row, col);
```

However, I don't see the point. Anything you want done to the `Mat` opencv provides. Any other operations you can do with the for loops above.

Comment: +0.2 for actually answering the question - who knows maybe they were integrating with some other library ...  +0.8 for your elaboration :)